# Refresh scroll location to current anchor name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

Heyo,

so I've got a `main_menu` with some `sub_menu`'s. The `main_menu li a[href]`'s link to the different pages and the `sub_menu li a[href]`'s link to specific locations inside each page with the `<a name="...">` attribute (f.e. from http://example.com/page to http://example.com/page#1). Now sinse this is a Website with a custom CMS, I can't change every single `<a href="...">` attribute of all the `li a`'s or else i will make the menu unable to eddit for people with less knowlage. So I redirect every of the `sub_menu li a`'s to the correct anchor name attribute link.

Now once I clicked on one of the `sub_menu li a`'s I will get redirected to the correct page and the correct anchor name attribute link. But I don't get exaktly to the point were the `<a name="...">` is located. The Viewport is allways above or below the element.

For some reason this doesn't happen in Chrome thoe. In Firefox, Edge and Internet Explorer I get this weird bug.

So I tried to refresh (not reload) the page and after that it works. So I decided to create a little script with jQuery that makes the page refresh after every `.load()` and this is what I came up with:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    $('html').load();
});
```

Now I'm not sure if this is the right approach to my Issue or if my Script is just not correct. But it doesn't work for me. What have I done wrong?

Comment: the code you've posted is not enough to well understand the problem

Comment: And the text isn't aswell? I need a Script that refreshes (not reloads) the page when it is loaded.

Comment: with that text we have to imagine what you mean. ten line of code are better than 1000 words

Comment: there are problems that need more code than text and than there are problems that need more text than code to explain

Comment: i don't have a huge script going on ... its just that 3 lines of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are causing `li a` with no `href` to change page with the anchor and having to reload to get the anchor positioning right? Have I understood that correctly?

Firstly I'd suggest that they should be `href` as they aren't the anchor, they're the link..?

With that aside, from what you've given (which probably should be more info generally), I'd guess that the position the viewport is at is where the element *was* before the page changed during loading and moved the element higher/lower. Chrome is probably timing the anchor positioning later than the other browsers (i.e. after more things are loaded/rendered).

I'd check this by temporarily disabling anything loading on the page that's causing DOM changes and moving the elements around during load. If that's the issue then you'll need to decide how best to handle that based on what is loading.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Not exactly no. I was talking about href's but I guess it wasn't clear enough. I updated my post a bit. But you have a verry good and helpfull point with the before loading change. I will look into that.